# stuck on loading image while trying to set image as wallpaper

Tags: java, android, image, android-wallpaper

i am creating images gallery  wallpaper app in which i am trying to set image as wallpaper.

when i try to set a image as wallpaper i gets stuck at image loading message.

this is the screenshot: it gets stuck here:

[image]

**tThis is the set wallpaper code:**

**set_wallpaper.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Set_Wallpaper extends Activity {

    private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int CROP_FROM_CAMERA = 2;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_wallpaper);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ImageView ing = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_page);
        ing.setImageResource(MainActivity.ICONS[position]);

        doCrop();
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
        /**
         * Open image crop app by starting an intent
         * ‘com.android.camera.action.CROP‘.
         */
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        /**
         * Check if there is image cropper app installed.
         */
        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                intent, 0);

        int size = list.size();

        /**
         * If there is no image cropper app, display warning message
         */
        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            /**
             * Specify the image path, crop dimension and scale
             */
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            /**
             * There is posibility when more than one image cropper app exist,
             * so we have to check for it first. If there is only one app, open
             * then app.
             */

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));
                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                /**
                 * If there are several app exist, create a custom chooser to
                 * let user selects the app.
                 */
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(
                            res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));

                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null,
                                    null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public class CropOption {
        public CharSequence title;
        public Drawable icon;
        public Intent appIntent;
    }

    public class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption> {
        private ArrayList<CropOption> mOptions;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CropOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CropOption> options) {
            super(context, R.layout.set_wallpaper, options);
            mOptions = options;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.set_wallpaper, null);

            CropOption item = mOptions.get(position);

            if (item != null) {
                ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_page))
                        .setImageDrawable(item.icon);
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name))
                        .setText(item.title);

                return convertView;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The following the code where i am swiping images and sending current showing image to set_wallpaper class on button click

**SwipeActivity.java**

```
package com.td.gridview;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

    protected int curruntPosition;
    protected int hh;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipe_view);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Here you can set the wallpaper
                curruntPosition = arg0;
                if (curruntPosition == arg0) {
                    hh = 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        //
        Button bx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xoom);
        bx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View vx) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (hh == 1) {
                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Full_Zoom.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i2.putExtra("id", curruntPosition);
                    startActivity(i2);
                } else {
                    // get intent data
                    Intent i3 = getIntent();

                    // Selected image id
                    int position = i3.getExtras().getInt("id");
                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Full_Zoom.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i2.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }

            }
        });
        //

        // set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub                       

                if (hh == 1) {
                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Set_Wallpaper.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i2.putExtra("id", curruntPosition);
                    startActivity(i2);
                } else {
                    // get intent data
                    Intent i3 = getIntent();

                    // Selected image id
                    int position = i3.getExtras().getInt("id");
                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Set_Wallpaper.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i2.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        int[] icons = MainActivity.ICONS;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return icons.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = SwipeActivity.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            // R.dimen.padding_large);
            // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(icons[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any other code you have not mentioned here, for displaying loading dialog

Comment: SwipeActivity.java is the class where i am swiping images and sending image to set_wallpaper class. set_wallpaper class is coded to get and set image as wallpaper.

Comment: you not getting me.where is the code which displays dialog box of 'loading image..' which you have shown in the image

Comment: @yuva ,  actually that message is comming from set_wallpaper class.
i am sending image from SwipeActivity class to set_wallpaper class.
please see my code again.

Comment: please see this line in swipeactivity class
`// set wallpaper on button click
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wll);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v2) {`

and see this line in set_wallpaper class

`@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_wallpaper);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    }`